# What is this modern look called and what is the template used for it?

Tags: html, css, layout

I haven't been paying attention to modern websites for a while, but in the few years or so a bunch of websites with the same, very smooth, very sleek presentation format have appeared.  Some examples:

- http://devatory.com/
- https://anyperk.com/
- http://www.datadoghq.com/
- https://www.pixlee.com/
- http://www.mparticle.com/
- http://www.rockhealth.com/
- http://vsevil.net/

Plenty more example abound, but here are the characteristics:

- Full page width layout,
- Large top bar with menu items on it, horizontal
- Seems to use images from some kind of standard set of images,
- Site map at the bottom

Is there a name for this style, or perhaps some kind of template kit that you can find somewhere for this?

Comment: Oh come on, __this is not opinion based__!  There has got to be a framework or something that people are using to get this very common layout.

Comment: Some of these websites are based on wordpress, whereas some are not. This is basically a specific style that can be implemented in any website with proper coding, I presume. I don't think there can be an answer to this.

Comment: There has to be a name for this style of site, it is so common,

Comment: Responsive design. View the source code for clues such as what WordPress theme was used, and look up that theme to see how it's described. Looking at the last link, the source has `wp-content/themes/salient`, and looking up the "Salient" WordPress theme, it states that it's "Responsive styling". Unfortunately, this site is not well-suited for design oriented questions - you would do better to ask those sorts of questions over at [User Experience](http://ux.stackexchange.com/), but be sure to check their FAQ's first.

Comment: @dan +1 for your detailed comment.